# error in constructing if statement in csh

Tags: csh

I tried to execute this if statement in c-shell but something wrong with the syntax that causes it not working

```
if(grep "hello" $HOME/file) then 
echo "I am here" 
endif


if(grep "hello" $HOME/file) then echo "I am here" end if
```

```
if: Expression Syntax.
```

Comment: There's a space between `end` and `if`; perhaps that's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In 'csh', the 'if' statement will only take 'expression'. Assuming your script want to check for the status of the 'grep' command, consider checking the '$status' immediately after executing the 'grep'.

```
grep "hello" $HOME/file
if ( $status === 0 ) then
    echo "I'm here"
end if

#Single line 'if'
grep "hello" $HOME/file
if ( $status === 0 ) echo "I'm here"
```